# SrSO4 Solubility in Acid

Tags: solubility

$\ce{SrSO4}$ is insoluble in water. Will it be more soluble in an acid solution? I know that if the anion is the conjugate base of a weak acid, it'll be more soluble. Does $\ce{SO4^2-}$ count as the conjugate base to $\ce{H2SO4}$ (strong acid) or $\ce{HSO4-}$?

Comment: Even HSO4- is not really a weak acid.

Comment: Wait so would it be more or less soluble in acid

Comment: [Wikipedia says "slightly soluble in acids"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium_sulfate) and yes, sulfate ion is conjugate base of HSO4-

Comment: BaSO4, that is even less soluble than SrSO4, is known to be somewhat soluble in concentrated H2SO4(particular data not handy).

Comment: In analytical chemistry books, $\ce{SrSO4}$ is said to be soluble in boiling concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ solutions. On the other hand, $\ce{BaSO4}$ is said to be soluble in concentrated sulfuric acid, because of the formation of both $\ce{HSO4^-}$ ion and of the complex  $\ce{H2[Ba(SO4)_2]}$, which is decomposed by dilution. Ref.; R. Delaby, Analyse qualitative minérale, Masson, Paris, 1950 (in French).